# Haskell and Lambda-Calculus: Implementing Alpha-Congruence (Alpha-Equivalence)

Tags: haskell, lambda-calculus

I am implementing an impure untyped lambda-calculus interpreter in Haskell.

I'm presently stuck on implementing "alpha-congruence" (also called "alpha-equivalence" or "alpha-equality" in some textbooks). I want to be able to check whether two lambda-expressions are equal or not equal to each other. For example, if I enter the following expression into the interpreter it should yield True (`\` is used to indicate the lambda symbol):

```
>\x.x == \y.y
True
```

The problem is understanding whether the following lambda-expressions are considered alpha-equivalent or not:

```
>\x.xy == \y.yx
???

>\x.yxy == \z.wzw
???
```

In the case of `\x.xy == \y.yx` I would guess that the answer is `True`. This is because `\x.xy => \z.zy` and `\y.yx => \z.zy` and the right-hand sides of both are equal (where the symbol `=>` is used to denote alpha-reduction).

In the cae of `\x.yxy == \z.wzw` I would likewise guess that the answer is `True`. This is because `\x.yxy => \a.yay` and `\z.wzw => \a.waw` which (I think) are equal.

The trouble is that all of my textbooks' definitions state that only the names of the *bound* variables need to be changed for two lambda-expressions to be considered equal. It says nothing about the *free* variables in an expression needing to be renamed uniformly also. So even though `y` and `w` are both in their correct places in the lambda-expressions, how would the program "know" that the first `y` represents the first `w` and the second `y` represents the second `w`. I would need to be consistent about this in an implementation.

In short, how would I go about implementing an error-free version of a function `isAlphaCongruent`? What are the **exact** rules that I need to follow in order for this to work?

I would prefer to do this without using de Bruijn indices.

Comment: They're not equivalent. Let's take `\x.xy`. You may rename `x` as you wish here and always obtain the same thing, but you can't rename `y` at will since it's not bounded by a lambda-abstraction. The same goes for `\y.yx`, but this time it's `x` that is not bound and thus cannot be renamed. This means you cannot rename them to make the congruence `\x.xy == \y.yx` true. See <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#Alpha_equivalence">wikipedia</a> for more details.

Comment: More specifically, `\x.xy` can be rewritten to `\a.ay`, and `\y.yx` can be rewritten to `\a.ax`, then it should be obvious that `\a.ay /= \a.ax`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are misunderstanding: different free variables are not alpha equivalent. So `y /= x`, and `\w.wy /= \w.wx`, and `\x.xy /= \y.yx`. Similarly, `\x.yxy /= \z.wzw` because `y /= w`.

Your book says nothing about free variables being allowed to be uniformly renamed because they are not allowed to be uniformly renamed.

(Think of it this way: if I haven't yet told you the definition of `not` and `id`, would you expect `\x. not x` and `\x. id x` to be equivalent? I sure hope not!)

Comment: It's exactly as Daniel says. When you see `x` as a free variable, it's not "any" `x`.

Comment: Thank you! Both comments have cleared up the confusion. No wonder my program wasn't working!